# Update Azure Table Storage Record via REST Web API

Tags: ajax, rest, asp.net-web-api, azure-table-storage

I am testing the REST API services for Azure Table Storage, I can get data without problems from the table, but I can't seem to be able to update records from javascript. Using Fiddler for the same operation instead works. The url is

https://"myaccount".table.core.windows.net/p73cca0789a574fd4a5b98012a8bb56bf(PartitionKey=%27Settings%27,RowKey=%27GeneralSettings_UICulture_1%27)?sv=2014-02-14&tn=p73cca0789a574fd4a5b98012a8bb56bf&spk=Settings&epk=Settings&sig=ue%2BdY4qa0Kk8MJ083jzuAqn7miGmIBV2C4DK6x7LL%2Bs%3D&se=2014-07-10T12%3A02%3A12Z&sp=raud

in Fiddler I set PUT as httpMethod and this as request body:

```
{
  Value: 'en',
  Version: 1,
  SettingName: 'GeneralSettings'
}
```

and it works OK, if I check the Table on Azure the value is updated correctly
From my web app instead, I use amplifyjs to make the ajax call, defining the method like this:

```
amplify.request.define('manageSetting', 'ajax', {
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            },                
            decoder: "defaultBehavior",
            type: httpMethod
        });
```

And I get a 400 Bad Request error, with the message: 'One of the request inputs is not valid'
In Firebug I can see these are my request headers:

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  46
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
DNT 1
Host    "myaccount".table.core.windows.net
Origin  https://localhost:444
Referer https://localhost:444/MyWebApp/projects/dde1b522-0c7d-40f1-8e08-5c39a1ce91ef
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
x-ms-date   Wed, 09 Jul 2014 14:10:24 GMT
x-ms-version    2014-02-14
```

The 'Put' tab of the request in Firebug states:

```
Value=en&Version=1&SettingName=GeneralSettings
```

Am I missing something?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured CORS for the table service for your account?  (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn535601.aspx)
If that’s not the issue, can you look at the Fiddler trace from the ajax call, and look at the differences between it and what Fiddler is sending directly?

Comment: Yes I did, the GET operations in fact work correctly. From Fiddler's 'Inspector' page I see the json object is sent correctly. The only difference I see is in Firebug, that in another Web API call with a POST method I see that the values sent to the server are displayed both in query string form (like for instance Value=en&Version=1&SettingName=GeneralSettings) AND also directly above, as 'Parameters' in key-value pairs. In my not-working PUT method I only see them as query string values. I have set the content-type to application/json, so I have no clue on what the issue might be

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it...
I had to JSON.stringify my data object, here's the new code:

```
amplify.request.define('manageSetting', 'ajax', {
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            decoder: "defaultBehavior",
            type: httpMethod
        });

        var data = options.settingObject;  //this is a js object in the form { key1: value1, key2: value2 }
        data = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : data;

        return amplify.request({
            resourceId: 'manageSetting',
            data: data,
            success: callbacks.success,
            error: callbacks.error
        });
```